# SQL- SameJobtTitleCount

Tags: sql

I am new to SQL. How do I count the jobs with same title as shown in the expected output?

```
SELECT 
BirthDate
,HireDate
,MaritalStatus + ' / ' + Gender AS socialStatus
,(SickLeaveHours)AS LeaveOfAbsenceHours
,JobTitle

FROM HumanResources.Employee
WHERE YEAR(HireDate)- YEAR(BirthDate)>=40 AND SalariedFlag = 1
ORDER BY BirthDate
```

**Expected output:** (https://ibb.co/hffD2xd)

I tried the below code but it counts the whole database job titles. I want it to be exactly as the expected output.

```
SELECT 
BirthDate
,HireDate
,MaritalStatus + ' / ' + Gender AS socialStatus
,(SickLeaveHours)AS LeaveOfAbsenceHours
,JobTitle

FROM HumanResources.Employee
WHERE YEAR(HireDate)- YEAR(BirthDate)>=40 AND SalariedFlag = 1
ORDER BY BirthDate
SELECT JobTitle, COUNT(JobTitle) AS 'SameJobTitleCount'
FROM HumanResources.Employee 
Group by JobTitle
HAVING COUNT(JobTitle) > 1
```

Comment: `WHERE YEAR(HireDate)- YEAR(BirthDate)>=40` is a very rough estimation.

Answer (score -1):

I'm new too but I will try to help anyways,
first of all I think you dont need the "HAVING COUNT(JobTitle) > 1" if you also want to display "0" for the JobTitles without 0 or 1 occurences.
Then leave out the second SELECT JobTitle in "SELECT JobTitle, COUNT(JobTitle) AS 'SameJobTitleCount'" , you are doing 2 requests there.
Just

```
SELECT 
BirthDate
,HireDate
,MaritalStatus + ' / ' + Gender AS socialStatus
,(SickLeaveHours)AS LeaveOfAbsenceHours
,JobTitle

FROM HumanResources.Employee
WHERE YEAR(HireDate)- YEAR(BirthDate)>=40 AND SalariedFlag = 1
ORDER BY BirthDate
,COUNT(JobTitle) AS 'SameJobTitleCount'
FROM HumanResources.Employee 
Group by JobTitle
```

The problem I found with GROUP BY is that it puts together the Employees with the same JobTitle so it only shows one Employee for each JobTitle, I couldnt find a better way

Comment: Im getting this error now. "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'."

Comment: and before you didnt? the two SELECTS  should not work as far as I know. Having FROM twice also shouldnt.